# Jordan Measure, Semi-closed sets and Partitions

Tags: measure-theory, set-partition

From earlier question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63155/jordan-measures-open-sets-closed-sets-and-semi-closed-sets). Consider

$$\mu \left( (0,1) \cap \mathbb Q \right) = 0$$

where 
$$(0,1) = \left(0,\frac{1}{3}\right)\cup \left[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right] \cup \left(\frac{2}{3}, 1\right)$$ so

$$ \mu ((0,1) \cap \mathbb Q ) = \mu \left(\left(0,\frac{1}{3}\right) \cap \mathbb Q \right) +  \mu\left( \left[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right] \cap \mathbb Q\right) + \mu\left(\left(\frac{2}{3}, 1\right) \cap \mathbb Q\right) = 0 + \frac{1}{3} + 0 \neq 0$$

contradiction with latter case. Why did my partition change the result?

**[solved]**

$\mu\left(\left[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right] \cap \mathbb Q\right) = 0$.

Comment: I think there's something you've gravely misunderstood. $\mu((0,1/3)) = 1/3$ and not $0$.

Comment: @kahen: $(0, \frac{1}{3}) = \mathbb Q \cap (0, \frac{1}{3}) = 0$ with respect to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: When you write "$(a,b)$" in the sense of an interval, it *always* means interval in the reals unless you have specified otherwise. And you didn't. As for your question --- your problem is that the rationals are not Jordan measurable. It's a good exercise to prove that a bounded subset of the reals is Jordan measurable if and only if its characteristic function is Riemann integrable (or equivalently Darboux integrable). And characteristic functions of rationals in intervals aren't Riemann integrable because they're everywhere discontinuous (in said interval).

Comment: [Continued] Terry Tao wrote a good introduction to "The Problem of Measure": http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/245a-prologue-the-problem-of-measure/